# Possible to retrieve name/artist of a song from radio station website?

Tags: api, parsing

I am trying to create a Shazam like service that works over the phone,

I was able to use Inspect Element to dig around and find an API call for WRIT FM.

I am trying to do the same for WKLH FM but I have not been able to find any references to any code that points to the currently playing song metadata.

The now playing page is here: http://player.listenlive.co/41851

It doesn't come up when doing View Page Source either,

Is there any tool I could use to pinpoint where the metadata is coming from? I need to be able to extract text in real time using a custom-made API so I can use that in my application (Asterisk PBX),

On the song history page, there IS some of this information available but it doesn't seem like it's offered in any predictable way which could be parsed:  http://player.listenlive.co/41851/en/songhistory

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot with the exact content of the webpage to be parsed as the example, and expected output.

Comment: @omegastripes Well, that's just the thing - I haven't any idea how I can find what I need to parse. It's not the parsing that's holding me up, it's finding the code I need to parse. I can't find it when Viewing page source or when using F12/Inspect Element.

Comment: The XHR by URL http://player.listenlive.co/41851/en/songhistory returns the response which contains the snippet `var songs = [...];`, you can parse all the necessary metadata from there.